# Is it possible to create a data frame graphic using arcpy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, arcpy

I'm interacting with an MXD using arcpy, and wish to create a graphic within a data frame - as with the Draw toolbar when working manually. The [GraphicElement](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/GraphicElement/00s300000040000000/) page says...

> The GraphicElement object provides access to properties that enables
>   its repositioning on the page layout as well as methods that allow for
>   duplicating and deleting existing graphic elements.

...which doesn't mention the ability to create a new graphic element. Is there another area I should be looking at in arcpy, or is this not currently supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are coming up against an ArcPy software limitation.

Although you cannot create a [GraphicElement](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s300000040000000) from scratch, as long as you have one graphic element present in your layout (even if it is placed off the page), then:

> Existing graphic elements can be cloned and deleted. This capability
>   was initially added to support the creation of dynamic graphic tables
>   on a page layout where each cell in the table can be outlined using
>   line graphics.

I take copies of an "off the page" graphic element and then move, resize, etc them.

The same workaround can also be used for text elements.

Comment: I have a great idea - every MXD should come with a hidden graphic ;)

Comment: ... so that a `copy` method could `clone` it, `elementPositionX`/`elementPositionY` it to the centre of the page, and make it a default `elementHeight` & `elementWidth`:-)