# Managing Leaders for Extent Indicators of Insets using ArcPy with Data Driven Pages?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, layouts, data-driven-pages, extent-indicators

I am working in data driven pages that need insets on some maps (not all). I found and have successfully managed to use this code below. However, I need to have leaders. Any ideas on how to manage extent indicator leaders in arcpy?

```
import arcpy, os
# Create an output directory variable
#
outDir = r"C:\TXT"  

# Create a new, empty pdf document in the specified output directory
# This will be your final product
finalpdf_filename = outDir + r"\FinalMapBook5.pdf"
if os.path.exists(finalpdf_filename): # Check to see if file already exists, delete if it does
  os.remove(finalpdf_filename)
finalPdf = arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentCreate(finalpdf_filename)


# Create a Data Driven Pages object from the mxd you wish to export
#
mxdPath = r"O:\Data\project_specific\cedar_milford\milfordtoCedar\Test_MXD\05858_hb_PHI_DE_cedar_to_milford_cut_sheets_JDS.MXD"
tempMap = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdPath)
tempDDP = tempMap.dataDrivenPages

# Create objects for the layout elements that will be moving, e.g., inset data frame, scale text
dataFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(tempMap, "Test")[0] 
narrow = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(tempMap, "MAPSURROUND_ELEMENT", "North Arrow")[0]

# Instead of exporting all pages at once, you will need to use a loop to export one at a time  
# This allows you to check each index and execute code to add inset maps to the correct pages
#
for pgIndex in range(1, 2 + 1, 1):

  # Create a name for the pdf file you will create for each page
  temp_filename = r"C:\TXT" + \
                            str(pgIndex) + ".pdf"
  if os.path.exists(temp_filename):
    os.remove(temp_filename)

  # The following if statements check the current page index against given values
  # If the current page index matches, it will execute code to set up that page
  # If not, the page remains as is
  # Note: If you created a text file containing this information, this is where
  # you would paste in that code

  # Code for setting up the inset map on the first page #
  if (pgIndex == 1):
    dataFrame.elementPositionX = 0.6644
    dataFrame.elementPositionY = 7.5622
    dataFrame.elementHeight = 3.025
    dataFrame.elementWidth = 5.8834
    insetExtent_1 = arcpy.Extent(614813.318397, 499413.131878, 615191.030877, 499607.335952)
    dataFrame.extent = insetExtent_1



  # Code to export current page and add it to mapbook
  tempDDP.exportToPDF(temp_filename, "RANGE", pgIndex)
  finalPdf.appendPages(temp_filename)


  # Clean up your page layout by moving the data frame and resetting its extent after exporting the page
  # This will reset the page to the basic layout before exporting the next page
  #

  dataFrame.elementPositionX = 1000 # Move inset data frame off the page
  narrow.elementPositionX = 1000
  dataFrame.scale = 350000000 # Change scale so extent indicator no longer visible in main data frame
  arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

# Clean up
#
del tempMap

# Update the properties of the final pdf
#
finalPdf.updateDocProperties(pdf_open_view="USE_THUMBS",
                             pdf_layout="SINGLE_PAGE")

# Save your result
#
finalPdf.saveAndClose()
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot manage leaders for extent indicators using ArcPy with ArcMap.

They need to be pre-authored into the map documents that you create map document objects from in ArcPy.

If you use ArcGIS Pro, then the Cartographic Information Model (CIM) can be accessed via ArcPy.  That may open up options to manipulate leaders but I have not yet investigated that.

Comment: I wonder if you can create fake leaders by manipulating graphics in arcpy.  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112428/is-it-possible-to-create-a-data-frame-graphic-using-arcpy

Comment: @Midavalo Using pseudo-leaders made from cloned graphics would I think be possible but non-trivial and any proof of concept should start from a code snippet developed by the user rather than some "found" code.

Comment: Yea, unfortunately I am not yet a hard core python programmer. Thanks for all the help, I think I have an Idea for using graphics